# Do I need to encrypt user data in database

Tags: encryption, databases

I have a user table with 20 columns. I am using argon2id to hash passwords but I was asked by the information security department to encrypt user data before saving it to the database.

I have questions about this request. Do I really need to do that? I have never seen that in practice.

Doing it will also have some cost when encrypting/decrypting and will decrease performance. And if in some way the secret key used by encrypt algorithm got lost, then all data will be lost.

Does this really make my user-sensitive data secure against the company getting breached?

Comment: @schroeder thank you for answer. it is actually requested by information security department. we were arguing on that. It is wanted because a very big company got hacked and user address are leaked. They are afraid of this.

Comment: Ok, then it seems like there needs to be more info on the situation. And it feels like there is more info needed about the threat.

Comment: We would definitely need more information to answer this... And I feel that both you and the infosec department need more information from each other.  I'd start by asking exactly what type of encryption is needed, how the keys will be stored, and how to prevent an attacker who has read access to the database from also getting the keys (presuming that they got access to the DB by having access to the application's config or source itself.)

Comment: "Just encrypt it" doesn't do much, if you're dealing with user data that's constantly being accessed by your application. Clearly, the means of decryption are accessible to the application (otherwise the data would be useless!) so it's not clear that there's any real gain. Don't encrypt anything "just for the sake of it". Have a particular threat model in mind, and use it to decide if some encryption scheme helps or not.

Comment: The cost of losing the key and the entire database must be weighed against the cost of the database contents being leaked to third parties.   Both are risks, which one costs more?  Are parts of the data more sensitive than others?  Would it help to store the most sensitive least accessed data in another smaller, more secure database instead?